# Permission violation, but the manifest does not request SMS or Call Log permission

Tags: android, google-play

Our 2 apps were removed from sale in the Play Store today due to a permission violation. Has anyone faced the same problem yet?

Note: Our app code doesn't contain the SMS or Call Log permission.

> Hi Developers at XXX LTD,
>
> After review, [App Name], net.xxx.xxx, has been removed from Google Play due to a policy violation. This app won’t be available to users until you provide us with more information through the Play Console.
>
> Issue: Violation of the Permissions policy
>
> You may only request permissions that are necessary to implement critical features or services currently available in your app. You may not use permissions that give access to user or device data for undisclosed, unimplemented, or disallowed features or purposes. SMS and Call Log Permissions are subject to additional restrictions; in order to use these permissions, you must first receive approval from Google Play.

Comment: make sure any of the underlying 3rd party libraries are not using them. for eg. if your app is using any of the payment gateway library they might be using that permissions.

Comment: a simple way to check @KaranMer suggestion would be to simply install the app and check the permissions used in the app settings in your phone

Comment: Don't forget, apps will be removed even you don't use the permissions but defined in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I've checked and it doesn't use both, see this
https://screencast.com/t/XMYV58lU2m2

Comment: Guys thanks, but I don't have both permission only have CALL_PHONE permission which is not restricted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all you can see that I've a Call permission in my manifest and I used Phone Call code in android with run time permission but that code can be replaced by Dial code so I replaced the code and then removed the permission from Manifest then re-uploaded the App and App is now Live again. Google official documents only disallow the permission for Call logs and SMS but with my experience they can not allow to use Call permission as well.

Removed permission:
CALL_PHONE

https://www.screencast.com/t/XMYV58lU2m2

Answer (score 3):

Want to initiate a phone call? Don’t use CALL_PHONE permission, use Dialer intent instead.

Set phoneNumber and use ACTION_DIAL.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

https://proandroiddev.com/no-more-sms-call-log-permissions-now-what-9b8226de7827

ACTION_CALL
added in API level 1
public static final String ACTION_CALL
Activity Action: Perform a call to someone specified by the data.

Input: If nothing, an empty dialer is started; else getData() is URI of a phone number to be dialed or a tel: URI of an explicit phone number.

Output: nothing.

Note: there will be restrictions on which applications can initiate a call; most applications should use the ACTION_DIAL.

Note: this Intent cannot be used to call emergency numbers. Applications can dial emergency numbers using ACTION_DIAL, however.

Note: if you app targets M and above and declares as using the Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE permission which is not granted, then attempting to use this action will result in a SecurityException.

Constant Value: "android.intent.action.CALL"

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent

Answer (score -1):

**You need to add a privacy policy**.

As the App permission have CONTACTS and PHONE permission, it is using users personal data which is contact. [https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/personal-sensitive/](http://As%20the%20App%20permission%20have%20CONTACTS%20and%20PHONE%20permission,%20it%20is%20using%20users%20personal%20data%20which%20is%20contact.%20https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/personal-sensitive/%20According%20to%20official%20doc,%20they%20have%20to%20show%20privacy%20policy) According to official doc, they have to add privacy policy

To add a privacy policy to your store listing:

1. Go to your Google Play Developer Console.
2. Select an app.
3. Select Store Listing.
4. Under "Privacy Policy," enter the URL where you have the privacy
   policy hosted online.
5. Select Save draft (new apps) or Submit update (existing apps).

and You need to add Terms & Condition / Privacy policy page in App, which will describe the use of phone calls in your App.

Comment: I don't think this is relevant.  The OP says they are not using call log or sms permissions.

Comment: In comments, he mentioned that he is using CALL_PHONE permission in app

Comment: If you think that privacy policy and/or ToC are needed to use unrestricted CALL_PHONE permission, then please point to a definitive source of this information.

Comment: As the App permission have CONTACTS and PHONE permission, it is using users personal data which is contact. [https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/personal-sensitive/](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/personal-sensitive/) According to official doc, they have to show privacy policy

Comment: This link may be relevant - I suggest you edit your answer and put it at the top.

Comment: Ohh yes sure  :)

Comment: Not relevant because call_phone doesn't collect any personal information also there is no doc where it mention that call_log permission required the privacy policy or special forms submit.

Comment: https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/ You can check in this link, its there

Answer (score -2):

I think you're overthinking it.  The permission blurb is the same for all permissions.  What it says is that (emphasis is mine):

> **You may only request permissions that are necessary to implement
>   critical features or services currently available in your app.** You may
>   not use permissions that give access to user or device data for
>   undisclosed, unimplemented, or disallowed features or purposes. SMS
>   and Call Log Permissions are subject to additional restrictions; in
>   order to use these permissions, you must first receive approval from
>   Google Play.

Just because you don't use SMS or Call Log permissions, it doesn't mean that you're not using something you shouldn't. I suggest you review ALL permissions that your app is using (as well as all 3rd party libraries that you use) - and try to identify which permission could be seen as violating the policy.  Further, you can always respond to the message via Google Play requesting clarification on what exact permission is being questioned.

Comment: You are right but I don't think I have used any permission which is not relevant or not used in app, and how to sure which permission is causing me the trouble(a needle in a haystack)